# How can I divide a collection into sub collections of 50 elements each in C#?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection that looks like this:

```
IList<TQBase> = hq;

public class TQBase
{
    public int i { get; set; }
    public int q { get; set; }
}
```

The collection has over 300 items in it.

Now I need to create a collection of these collections such that:

```
h[0] = the first fifty elements of hq
h[1] = the next fifty elements of hq
...
h[n] = any remaining elements of hq
```

Can anyone suggest a way that I can create the second collection. Is this something that 
I could do with Linq or is there an easier way?

Comment: The term you are looking for is a paging algorithm.

Comment: Answered here already: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20036379/552139

Comment: @fejesjoco: That answers a different question (imho).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `GroupBy`:

```
IEnumerable<List<TQBase>> groups = hq.Select((t, index) => new{ t, index })
    .GroupBy(x => x.index / 50)
    .Select(xg => xg.Select(x => x.t).ToList());
```

Answer (score 3):

```
List<List<TQBase>> result = new List<List<TQBase>>();

for(var i = 0; i < hq.Length; i+= 50){
   result.Add(hq.Skip(i * 50).Take(50).ToList());
}
```