# Every nth Item In A Collection in VB.Net

Tags: .net, vb.net

Nearly identical to [How can I get every nth item from a List<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682615/how-can-i-get-every-nth-item-from-a-listt)

But I'm having trouble turning

```
 List<T> list = originalList.Where((t,i) => (i % 5) == 0).ToList();
```

Into VB.Net code.

Comment: You may find this helpful in the future for problems like this: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/. This tool can convert almost any C# code to the equivalent VB.Net code.  It works perfectly on this code sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Literally, that would be:

```
dim list as List(of T) = originalList.Where(Function(t, i) (i mod 5) = 0).ToList()
```

Answer (score 4):

It becomes

```
Dim list as List(Of T) = originalList.Where(Function(t,i) (i Mod 5) = 0).ToList()
```

[Lambdas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx#Y200) in Visual Basic use the `Function` and `Sub` keywords.