# Every Nth Item RavenDB

Tags: c#, ravendb

Any way I can get the every Nth doc in RavenDB?

I tried something like this, as seen on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/682644/3638742):

```
    Query<MyDoc, MyDoc_Index>().Where((x, i) => i % nStep == 0);
```

I get the following error:

> Could not understand how to translate '(i % 1000)' to a RavenDB query.
>   Are you trying to do computation during the query? RavenDB doesn't
>   allow computation during the query, computation is only allowed during
>   index. Consider moving the operation to an index.

I don't have a problem adding a reduce to my index if I have to. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the `.Skip()` method instead?

```
MyDoc nthValue = session.Query<MyDoc, MyDoc_Index>().Skip(nStep-1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I have but it turns out into an ugly aggregated query if you want to get every 5th document over a large collection.
I was wondering if there was some syntax sugar somewhere.

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer because it seems it's the only way to do it. I hope no one has to do the same because of all the database trips it causes.

Comment: @fgauna: Is the data sorted when you perform this? Otherwise, you won't have control over what comes back. The data may not be the same every time you execute it.

Comment: Yes it's sorted by a DateTimeOffset property I added to the document.