# How can i split a string and remove every nth element?

Tags: c#, split

I'm looking to do something like this

```
public string[] getArray() {

    string text = "1 ab cd 2 ef gh 3 ij kl 4 mn";
    string[] arr = text.Split(" ").remove(every third element); //remove the 1,2,3,4 etc

    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get every nth item from a List<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682615/how-can-i-get-every-nth-item-from-a-listt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [use Linq to skip every nth element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/682644/2791540).

```
public string[] getArray() {

    string text = "1 ab cd 2 ef gh 3 ij kl 4 mn";
    string[] arr = text.Split(" ").Where((x, i) => i % 3 != 0).ToArray();
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: I guess you made some mistake and mean `text.Split(' ').Where((x, i) => (i) % 3 != 0).ToArray()` 

Comment: I honestly didn't read the question very closely. It's going to be some variation of `Where` and `%3`.